Joint pdf given one marginal pdf and a conditional pdf

$\textit{Bertsekas (2008)}$
In this example, we know that $f_{X}(x)=\frac{1}{50}\exp(-\frac{x}{50})$ and we also have the conditional relation that $Y$ follows a normal distribution with zero mean and s.d. one tenth of the vehicle's speed; but how can I arrive at the expresSion for $f_{Y|X}(y|x) /f_{Y|X=x}(y)$; on first approach I'd just write
$$ \large f_{Y|X}(y|x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\frac{x}{10}}e^{-\frac{y^2}{\frac{2x^2}{100}}}$$
How can I justify that $Y|X=x$ has mean $x$?

Pay close attention to the wording of the example. It says "the police radar's measurement $Y$ has an error which is modeled as a normal variable with zero mean ..."
The measurement $Y$ itself is not normal with zero mean. Instead, $$Y = X + \text{error},$$
where $\text{error} \sim \text{Normal}(0, (X/10)^2)$.
So, conditioned on knowing $X = x$, $Y \sim \text{Normal}(x, (x/10)^2)$.
